# get logcat of the android app by ruby?

Tags: ruby, calabash-android

is there any way to get a logcat by using ruby?
actually, I use calabash-android framework in order to write some acceptance tests of the android app. However, I have to get the logcat. There is a parametr to use for authenticating in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by:

```
log = `adb logcat -d | grep "tag_name"`
```